# Boost's data-driven tests' join operator `+` corrupts first column

Tags: c++, boost, boost-test

Consider the following code:

```
BOOST_DATA_TEST_CASE(
      sampleTest,
      (data::make(1) ^ data::make(2)) + (data::make(3) ^ data::make(4)),
      var1,
      var2)
{
  std::cout << var1 << "," << var2 << std::endl;
}
```

The output I expect is:

```
1,2
3,4
```

However, `var1` appears to be corrupt:

```
$> ./MyTests --run_test=Tests/sampleTest
Running 2 test cases...
202875304,2
202875304,4

*** No errors detected
$> ./MyTests --run_test=Tests/sampleTest
Running 2 test cases...
83976616,2
83976616,4

*** No errors detected
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I get a warning (treated as an error, since I use `-Werror`) on the dataset line: `error: returning reference to temporary [-Werror=return-local-addr]`. Are you using a high warning level, and do you get any such warning?

Comment: @FredLarson I never got a warning but if I turn it into an error I do indeed see it: `join.hpp:57:58: error: returning reference to local temporary object [-Werror,-Wreturn-stack-address]`

Comment: Yeah, something about this is producing undefined behavior. I think it has something to do with joining the results of zips, but I haven't tried data-driven tests before.

Answer (score 2):

That's a bug. Long story short: please report it to the library maintainers.

Indeed, the `zip` operation returns a tuple `std::tuple<int const&, int const&>`:

and though the dataset itself is properly alive at the time, the tuple is returned by reference in the `join` operation...:

```
    sample const&       operator*() const   { return m_first_size > 0 ? *m_it1 : *m_it2; }
```

The proper fix would be to extend the [dataset concept](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/libs/test/doc/html/boost_test/tests_organization/test_cases/test_case_generation/datasets.html#boost_test.tests_organization.test_cases.test_case_generation.datasets.dataset_interface) to not only have a `::sample` type¹ but also a `::reference` type. That's quite an invasive change.

---

¹ strangely not documented at this time

Comment: You should probably have included a link so they don't have to do double work.